# Pagination in laravel for displaying awkwardly

Tags: html, laravel-4, pagination, eloquent

I have the following code to display unsolved questions from the database

```
<h2> Unsolved Questions </h2>
    @if(!$questions)
        <p> There are no Unsolved Questions </p>
    @else
        <ul>
            @foreach($questions as $question)
                <li> {{ $question->questions }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>

        {{ $questions->links() }}
    @endif
```

The result displays properly however the pagination results shows like this

```
«
1
2
»
```

Where could the problem be?

Controller

```
    public function create()
    {
        return View::make('questions.create')
            ->with('title', 'Q&A ask/Answer question')
            ->with('questions', Question::unsolved());
    }
```

**Model**

```
    public static function unsolved()
    {
        return static::where('solved', '=', 0)->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->paginate(5);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to change this by editing apps/config/view.php

and changed pagination from `'pagination' => 'pagination::slider-3',`

to `'pagination' => 'pagination::slider',`

this gave me a pagination that looks like this `

```
« 1 2 »
```